# Spring HATEOAS and Ribbon with Eureka - host name in created links

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-hateoas, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using Spring HATEOAS to build and access a REST service. The service registers itself with a eureka server, and I use Ribbon (via `@LoadBalanced RestTemplate`) to call it.

Per default, the requests are made for the hostname (in the `Host` header) for the resolved instance. This causes the LinkBuilder in Spring HATEOAS to generate links for this host. When Ribbon makes a request to follow a link, it tries to lookup the link host name in eureka again and of course gets no result.

What is the best level to address this situation? After receiving the links with the first result, I guess it would be acceptable to direct the immediate following requests to the same service instance, I still feel making all requests to the symbolic service name would be better.

Is it possible to configure Ribbon to make requests with that service name in the Host header (assuming no virtual hosting in the target service, that seems to be a valid assumption)?

Otherwise is it possible to set a canonical base URL for the link builder in HATEOAS? (defining all links as complete strings is not acceptable for me)

My solution/workaround for now is explicitly setting an `X-Forwarded-Host` header when requesting the root resource. This works, but is a bit verbose and cumbersome.

```
Traverson traverson = new Traverson(URI.create("http://photo-store/"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, MediaTypes.HAL_JSON).setRestOperations(imageService);
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.set("X-Forwarded-Host", "photo-store");
String original = this.traverson.follow("image:original").withHeaders(httpHeaders).asTemplatedLink().expand(photoId).getHref();
```

(Side question: can I override the `Host` header like that, or is it treated special in Ribbon or RestTemplate?)

I feel that there should be a more declarative or convention or configuration based way to deal with this. Is there?

Comment: Is the root service knows the correct URL to call, why bother trying to use Eureka and RIbbon?  Why not just use a normal `RestTemplate` to make the request?

Comment: Not sure I understand. There is one consuming service. It requests the root resource of the target service using load balanced RestTemplate, with the eureka service name. w/o my workaround, the response contains links to the physical address of the responding instance. Requests to these URLs don't work with the same load balanced RestTemplate. One approach would be to make the requests to these URLs with another normal RestTemplate. I prefer to get links to the eureka service name, and make requests with the same RestTemplate, at it seems more resilient. Feel free to convince me otherwise :)

Comment: It seems fair to point out that the context is a playground project where I explore Spring Cloud, nothing aimed at production.

Comment: I think either solution (your "workaround" or using a second RestTemplate) is fine.  In fact we document how to use multiple RestTemplates in the Spring Cloud documentation.

Comment: Yes both approaches work, and make it possible to solve this. The point of my question is though: I think it shows that the story of the spring infrastructure to consume a redundant REST service built with a spring library has rough edges. What are the right approaches to soften these rough edges? Should HATEOAS make it possible to build links for a canonical service URL? Should Ribbon have a way to configure the host header to use? _Having_ to use a second non-lb RestTemplate _or_ _having to specify a Host header_ in application code for every request that returns links seems not ideal.

Comment: I think the ideal solution is to solve the problem from the HATEOAS side.  HATEOAS has ways of customizing the [links](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.20.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#fundamentals.links) being returned.  Since the app using HATEOAS knows the app name being registered with Eureka, you should be able to create links using this name that would work with Ribbon clients.

Comment: Thanks for your help and point of view. Strictly speaking, HATEOAS has little ways to "customize" the links it builds (except for the `X-FORWARDED-*` headers), what it offers is the possibility to create links completely "by hand" and not use the link building facilities. This is not ideal. I created [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/516).

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem. I resolved it by adding interceptor which adds X-Forwarded-Host header to every request.

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(singletonList((ClientHttpRequestInterceptor) (request, body, execution) -> {
        request.getHeaders().add("X-Forwarded-Host", request.getURI().getHost());
        return execution.execute(request, body);

    }));
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using my own linkBuilder which fetches the name of the service from the properties and uses that as a Hostname. This is pretty basic, but easy to use and implement. If you want to use the whole spring hateoas link discovery magic sauce, you need to do more. But right now I'm searching for a solution that fits better with Spring Hateoas 1.x myself, so maybe I'll find a better answer soon.

The quick and dirty way:

```
@Component
public class MyLinkBuilder {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String servicename;

    public Link getLink(String path) {
        String root = "http://" + servicename;
        return new Link(root + path);
    }


    public Link getLink(String path, String rel) {
        return getLink(path, LinkRelation.of(rel));
    }

    public Link getLink(String path, LinkRelation rel) {
        String root = "http://" + servicename;
        return new Link(root + path, rel);
    }
}
```